# TypeError: fields.map is not a function when doing next dynamic sitemap with next-sitemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, sitemap.xml

I am trying to do dynamic sitemap for my site and here is my code:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { getServerSideSitemap, ISitemapField } from 'next-sitemap';
import { makeSlugFromString } from '../../lib/helpers';
import { BaseNCategories } from '../../lib/generalConstants';

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: any) => {
  const response = await fetch('http://baseapi/v3/category-list');
  const categoriesData = await response.json();
  const categories: any[] = categoriesData.cat;
  const categoryBn = BaseNCategories.filter((baseCategory) => {
    return categories.some((category) => category.CategoryID === baseCategory.CategoryID);
  });
  const fields: ISitemapField[] = categoryBn.map((category) => ({
    loc: `baseApi/${makeSlugFromString(category.Slag)}`,
    lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
    // priority: 0.7,
    // changefreq: 'daily',
  }));
  console.log({ fields });
  return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields);
};

export default function Site() {}
```

The error I'm getting is "field.map is not a function". I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

categoryBn is not an array
Since categoryBn is derived from BaseNCategories using the filter function, it should always be an array. However, to be certain, you can add a check before creating the fields array to ensure categoryBn is indeed an array.

Replace this:

```
    const fields: ISitemapField[] = categoryBn.map((category) => ({
  loc: `baseApi/${makeSlugFromString(category.Slag)}`,
  lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
}));
```

With this:

```
    if (!Array.isArray(categoryBn)) {
  console.error('categoryBn is not an array:', categoryBn);
  return { notFound: true }; // Return a 404 page or an error page as needed.
}

const fields: ISitemapField[] = categoryBn.map((category) => ({
  loc: `baseApi/${makeSlugFromString(category.Slag)}`,
  lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
}));
```

Comment: categoryBn is an array and also fields is an array.don't know why the error occured

Comment: categoryBn: [
  { CategoryName: 'ফুটবল', Slag: 'football', CategoryID: '1215' },
  { CategoryName: 'ক্রিকেট', Slag: 'cricket', CategoryID: '1214' }
]

Comment: Therefore, I think you should check the following items carefully. maybe makeSlugFromString is not returning the expected value:
If makeSlugFromString(category.Slag) returns a non-string value, this could cause issues. Ensure that the makeSlugFromString function is returning a valid string that can be concatenated to 'baseApi/'. 2- categoryBn contains null or undefined values: If categoryBn contains null or undefined values, it could cause issues when creating the fields array. Ensure that the BaseNCategories and API response are well-formed and do not have unexpected values.

Comment: sir here makeSlugFromString is also returning string and the  BaseNCategories and API response are return array of objects